# Eloquent: Alias from outer query can't be referenced in subquery

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have the following query:

```
DB::table('dining_tables as dt')
        ->whereNotExists(function($query){
            $query
                ->from('booking_allocations as ba')
                ->join('time_slots as ts', 'ba.slot_id', '=', 'ts.id')
                ->where('ba.booking_date', '=', '2019-01-27')
                ->where('ts.start_time', '>=', '12:00 PM')
                ->where('ts.end_time', '<=', '1:00 PM')
                ->where('ba.table_id', '=', 'dt.id')
                ->select(DB::raw('null'));
        })
        ->where('dt.capacity', '>=', 4)
        ->select('id')
        ->limit(1)
        ->get();
```

Notice that the alias `dt` created in the outer query is being referenced in the subquery in the following line:

```
->where('ba.table_id', '=', 'dt.id')
```

This leaves me with the following error:

> Illuminate/Database/QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[22P02]:
>   Invalid text representation: 7 ERROR:  invalid input syntax for
>   integer: "dt.id" (SQL: select "id" from "dining_tables" as "dt" where
>   not exists (select null from "booking_allocations" as "ba" inner join
>   "time_slots" as "ts" on "ba"."slot_id" = "ts"."id" where
>   "ba"."booking_date" = 2019-01-27 and "ts"."start_time" >= 12:00 PM and
>   "ts"."end_time" <= 1:00 PM and "ba"."table_id" = dt.id) and
>   "dt"."capacity" >= 4 limit 1)'

It's taken me half a day to realize the error can be circumvented by this replacement code:

```
->where('ba.table_id', '=', DB::raw('dt.id'))
```

NOTE: The wrapping of `DB::raw()` around the offending alias.

Now, the query works as expected. I would like to understand what might be happening here.

Comment: When you use the variables from out side of function, then you have to use `use($variable)` along with function.

Comment: You are right, except he's no doing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`whereNotExists` internally makes a separate query:

https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.7/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php#L1435
https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.7/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php#L1404
https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.7/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php#L2772

`dt` is known to only the 'higher' instance of db builder.

Because of that, db builder, in your nested where, treats it as a string, and since `ba.table_id` is an integer, the value of type string cannot be used in that context.

When you use db raw - it just puts it as it is into the sql, where it works as supposed.